# Resize the other column witdh in listview when some are visible/invisible

Tags: android, listview, resize, adapter

I want to display a table with several column, but it's not adapt to the phones. Thus I dedided to use a ListView whose item are constituted with different textview, each representing a column. In add, I put togglebuttons above the listview to make the selected column visible or not. And it works fine.

However, when I hide a column, it remains a blank, the other visible columns don't use this new space for themselves. So, **how to change it in order that visible columns resize themselves** ?

Here the getView of my adapter (I don't put all the columns, it's just for the example)

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
        R.layout.solvent_item, parent, false);
}

TextView name = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.name);
TextView elution = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.elution);
TextView viscosity = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.viscosity);
TextView refraction = ViewHolder.get(convertView, R.id.refraction);

HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);
name.setText(item.get(NAME));
elution.setText(item.get(ELUTION));
viscosity.setText(item.get(VISCOSITY));
refraction.setText(item.get(REFRACTION));


if (SolventActivity.elutionChecked) {
    elution.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    elution.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

if (SolventActivity.viscosityChecked) {//if the toglebutton is on
    viscosity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    viscosity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

if (SolventActivity.refractionChecked) {
    refraction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    refraction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

return convertView;
}
```

the xml file for listview item is just made of several textview.

And if you want (but it's not the most important), the toglleClicked method:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
// Is the toggle on?
boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

if (on) {

    switch ((String) ((ToggleButton) view).getTextOn()) {
    case "Elution":
    elutionChecked = true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    break;
    case "Viscosity":
    viscosityChecked = true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    break;
    case "Refraction":
    refractionChecked = true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

} else {
    switch ((String) ((ToggleButton) view).getTextOn()) {
    case "Elution":
    elutionChecked = false;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    break;
    case "Viscosity":
    viscosityChecked = false;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    break;
    case "Refraction":
    refractionChecked = false;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: Try using `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the view's visibility to `View.GONE`, instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

According to the docs:

View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.